# cy.trigger() throws "cy.trigger() can only be called on a single element.in Cypress

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

For my application, I have to select multiple items and perform drag and drop operation, but I got the following error.

> cy.trigger() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements.

```js
cy.get('item1').click();

cy.get('item2')
  .click({ctrlkey:true})
  .trigger('dragstart',{dataTransfer}))
  .trigger('drag',{});

cy.get('targetelement')
  .trigger('dragover', { dataTransfer })
  .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer })
  .trigger('dragend', { dataTransfer });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every drag and drop has some variation, so this might not work for you. See [Issue: Move the cursor (Drag and Drop) #845](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/845#issuecomment-353380394)

> There isn't a generic answer for this - it depends on what your app is bound to, and what events and properties it's listening for.

If the `dragstart` event listener is attached to `document` you can use

```js
cy.document()
  .its('documentElement')
  .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer: {} });
```

---

I used this CodePen [Mouse Droppings](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/XJPjOj) as a basic multi-select drag-and-drop example app.

It has different events, which I've substituted below your events in the test,

- `dragover` changed to `dragenter`
- `drop` changed to `dragleave`

but ***you will use the events applicable to your app***.

Hopefully the key principle `cy.document().trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer: {} })` also works with your app.

**My test**

```js
it('drags and drops multiple items', () => {

  cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/index.html') // CodePen exported and run locally

  cy.contains('Item 0').click();                    // select 1st item
  cy.contains('Item 2').click({ctrlKey:true});      // also select 3rd item

  cy.document()
    .its('documentElement')
    .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer: {} })

  cy.get('ol').eq(2)                                // get the target

    // .trigger('dragover', { dataTransfer: {} })
    .trigger('dragenter', { dataTransfer: {} })

    // .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer: {} })
    .trigger('dragleave', { dataTransfer: {} })

    .trigger('dragend', { dataTransfer: {} });

  cy.get('ol').eq(2).contains('Item 0');            // verify 1st item moved
  cy.get('ol').eq(2).contains('Item 2');            // verify 3rd item moved


})
```

The result is items 0 & 2 from the first list end up on the third list.

Comment: My selection of 2 items and targets were clearly identified but the drag and drop was not working even after changing code as suggested. Got the below error cy.trigger() failed because it requires a DOM element.

Comment: cy.get('Item1").click({ctrlkey:true});
  cy.get('Item3")..click({ctrlKey:true})
  cy.document()
  .trigger('dragstart',{dataTransfer:{}})

cy.get('target-zone')
  .trigger('dragenter',{dataTransfer:{}})
  .trigger('dragleave',{dataTransfer:{}})
  .trigger('dragend',{dataTransfer:{}});

Comment: The error is probably not related to the `cy.document().trigger()`, otherwise I would get the same error. You have used `cy.get('target-zone').trigger()` but above you wrote `cy.get('targetelement').trigger()`. Please check your selectors carefully.

Comment: Having said that, maybe your `dragstart` event handler is more fussy. You can try `cy.document().its('documentElement').trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer: {} })` or `cy.get('body').trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer: {} })`

Comment: yeah that was typo error, it was cy.get('targetelement').trigger() only. I tried changing the code to cy.document().its('documentElement').trigger('dragstart',{dataTransfer:{}}); but still it is giving the same error this time it is throwing error in the dragleave saying cy.trigger() failed because it requires a DOM element.

Comment: Ok, as I said above **you will use the events applicable to your app**. The events `dragenter` and `dragleave` may not be the ones your app needs. You should play around with different events - `dragover` and `drop` are more common.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the workaround provided. My app expect dragevent, I constructed the dragstart with eventconstructor and that solved the problem .trigger('dragstart', { eventConstructor: 'DragEvent',dataTransfer, force: true }).trigger('drag',{});

Comment: Cheers, it would be good to have that info as an answer (for future reference) and mark it as accepted.